# Classifying but not locating entities within a text with spaCy model

Tags: machine-learning, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Is there a way to 'force' a trained spaCy model to classify, so not locate, given strings within a text?

In my case, I want to build a NER model that categorizes toponyms within a text as a certain class, for instance 'city' or 'country'. So the model does not need to locate the toponyms. For each text file it needs to process a list, dictionary etc of the toponyms within it as an argument, and then assign that toponym with the most likely class based on the surrounding text.

Also, is there an option to let spaCy 'ignore' the individual characters of a toponym and only train the model by looking at the surrounding text?

If I try to set the entities without specifying the label, print(doc.ents) returns an empty set.

```
doc = nlp("Germany is further from Japan than Moscow")

doc.set_ents([Span(doc, 0, 1), Span(doc, 4, 5), Span(doc, 6, 7)])

print(doc.ents)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```